# Mobile App with static content

Tags: html, mobile, jquery-mobile

I am developing a mobile app using HTML5 and JQuery Mobile because I want the application to be cross platform. The app has only static content. The content headings will be displayed as a ListView and upon selection of an item, the details of that particular item will be displayed.

My question is about the approach that would work best for all platforms. Should I just create individual static pages for all details and link the list items to them? If I just want to use one detail page and just plug in the content based on the selection, how can I do that? I can't also  possibly store the info in a database as each platform supports a different DB.

I also want the user to be able to favorite an item and manage that list separately. That list will be persistent so that the user can see it whenever the app is launched later.

Please let me know the best approach for these. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a "best" answer here, but here's my solution.

You could combine JQuery Mobile with PHP (or another language) to connect to a database and get the information you need.

I'm working on a mobile site which is using PHP and JQuery Mobile to connect to a Wordpress MySQL DB. Once it's all sorted out it works quite well and I haven't run into any of the DOM issues that can occur with dynamically generated content in JQuery Mobile. Sometimes if additional items are displayed after the page is loaded into the DOM, JQuery Mobile will not style them correctly.

Comment: Since the information is static, I want the application to be completely downloadable/installed and work offline. Considering this, how can I design the application so that it won't need a webserver to serve content?